# Calendar and getTimeInMillis(). Android.

Tags: android, time, calendar, systemtime

I have next code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, mYear); /2011
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth); /04
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);/13 
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, mHour); /11
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute); /53 
    System.out.println("Cal time "+ cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("System time " +System.currentTimeMillis());
```

cal time    64775494376227 
System time  1302724616231
What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Calendar.getInstance()` is already initialized to the current date/time.  You're returning the millis time for for sometime in 4022...not 2011.  See [the JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for more info.