# AlarmManager stops to work

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I though, after the last changes on my code, that my "Timer Receiver" works, but it is not...

I can start the manager and having the Receiver be called, then, after some hours, the AlarmManager stops to work.

I have a code in my App to check if the AlarmManager runs, and it says, that it does, but the Receiver will not be called.

Here my code:

```
  private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
  private PendingIntent checkPendingIntent;

  public void initTimer()
  {
    this.alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.main.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    this.alarmActive = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.main, 0,
        new Intent(this.main, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    this.checkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.main, 0,
                  new Intent(this.main, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  }

  public void startTimer(String frequency)
  {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long millis = 0;

    if(frequency.compareTo("1HOUR") == 0)
      millis = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR;
    if(frequency.compareTo("12HOUR") == 0)
      millis = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY;
    if(frequency.compareTo("1DAY") == 0)
      millis = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
    if(frequency.compareTo("1WEEK") == 0)
      millis = 7 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(calendar.before(now))
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    if(!this.timerSet)
      Logger.debug("Starting update checker (" + frequency + ")");
    else
      Logger.debug("Restarting update checker (" + frequency + ")");
    this.timerSet = true;
    this.alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        millis, this.checkPendingIntent);
  }
```

Well, this.alarmActive is true, so I expected that it works, and of course the method startTimer will NOT be called again.
But I can see in my logs on my phone and my server (the Receiver just send an HTTP-Request), that the Receiver will not be called...

Can someone say me, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot
Luca Bertoncello

Comment: are you trying in HTC device ?

Comment: No. I have a Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: Ok, at what particular interval you are calling your AlarmManager again ?

Comment: Right now one hour. But I tried 12 hours, too, and it didn't work, too

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5654906/996493) is the problem with your code too, I suggest you to use Constant number like 60 * 60  instead of `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` and try again.

Comment: Well, in the first version of my code, I used System.currentTimeMillis(), then (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249057/alarmmanager-dont-run-as-expectly) I got the suggestion to use this code... I'll try this evening to change the code again.

Comment: Well, I restarted the program a couple of hours ago, and set the check every hour. It runs perfectly with my original code... I can't understand why it stopped to work...

Comment: what do you mean by original code ? do you mean a static value one ?

Comment: I mean, the code I original posted today, with this.alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), millis, this.checkPendingIntent);

Comment: hmm... ok may be you need to implement logs to checkit out why it stops or why its running.

Comment: A log system exists, but I can just see, that the Receiver wasn't called... I log when the AlarmManager will be started and stopped, but I can't log when it crashes or it will be deleted from system... :(

Comment: That's why I am asking you to implement custom logs.

Comment: I do have a custom log system... But if Android decides to kill my AlarmManager, how can I log it? :)

Comment: well, By Custom Logs I mean to say save log details in physical file. So that later on you can open the file and check what happened when error occurred and at which step the error occurred. Getting my point ?

Comment: Of course! I ALREADY DO it! And in this file is nothing to see about stopping the AlarmManager